# How to ignore leading special characters in sphinx search?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

For example, we want the search term "Test" to match the word "@Test" and "(Test)"in the results.

Comment: it does this by default. Unless you have added these chars to the charset_table in the config

Comment: thats it, thanks.  If you move that to an answer I can select it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it does this by default. Unless you have added these chars to the charset_table in the config

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with escape character backslash just before special characters.
Also check there is **EscapeString** function available in sphinx API.